# Compare two audio files using their waveforms

Tags: php, python, wav, waveform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparison of two waveforms of audio files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735871/comparison-of-two-waveforms-of-audio-files)

I found a php function which generates waveforms from wav files, I modified it and now it match my needs, it works well.

Waveforms seems to be so unique for every single wav file, so maybe it is possible to compare two audio files using their waveforms to see how close b.wav is to a.wav? Is it a good idea at all?

I wrote some php functions to compare two waveforms (JPG) pixel by pixel. After some test i get the following result: for two different audio files average difference is ~97% result as expected, but I dont know how will it work in real code.

Can someone give their opinion on this idea and maybe some useful hints :)

I am trying to compare two audio files to see how close is b.wav to a.wav.

P.S: my wav files are almost same, the only difference is vocal.

Comment: You are not showing any code or anything we could comment on and this is likely more suited for CodeReview.SE anyway.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Comparing audio by looking at _picture files_ of the waveforms is like comparing food by looking at it, rather than tasting. Why don't you just compare the .wavs directly, or some peak- or RMS-envelope?

Comment: @jeroen if it is possible to calculate difference between two audio files using their waveforms

Comment: @leftaroundabout can you give an example on how exactly to do this? The only difference between my wavs is only the vocal.

Answer (score 14):

I make similar task in university. And I use C++.

For compare I made steps:

1. Split audio files to chunks about 1 sec. each.
2. Calculate Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) for each chunk.
3. Calculate correlation between the FFT from the first file and the FFT from the second file. It for each chunk.
4. Check what for all chunk correlation is more then 80%. This value was enough for my project.

Comment: That's already quite advanced and should work very well. Of course, one needs to take care for issues such as proper [windowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) of the chunks. If the files differ in the vocals, it might work even better if you only consider the bass range, i.e. trimming all the FFT results to the first few bins.

Comment: +1 for giving a feasible answer, rather than "this is really complicated and you should read up on the subject; lots of research has been done and it's still really complicated."

Answer (score 2):

Comparing audio on their waveform is one way to go. But it doesnt realy match one audio file with another. All it matches is the difference in amplitude over some time. So if your goal is to compare that, a waveform comparisment is correct.

If you actually want to compare audio like shazam or something works, read up on [how-does-shazam-recognize-song](http://www.soyoucode.com/2011/how-does-shazam-recognize-song) or [An Industrial-Strength Audio Search Algorithm](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think comparing a graphical waveform is of much use when comparing signals. Instead, you should compare the signals themselves (`array`s of `float`s or `int`s).

There are a lot of signal processing methods that can provide some sort of similarity measure. As a first, simple attempt the [cross correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) function comes to mind.