# How to Compare two sounds files using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, audio

I have a project and I need to know how I can to do it.

I need to store a Mp3 file in database using Laravel.
After that I need for a user to record their work and save it into a Mp3 file as well.
Afterwards I want to compare these two sound files to know if their pronunciation was right and whether it's almost identical to the first file or not.

How can I do this?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735871/comparison-of-two-waveforms-of-audio-files

Comment: are there any examples in laravel ? because I don't understand the main idea of this method

Comment: You need to run system utlity such as `ffmpeg` to compare two files you can run that via php exec command to get the results you want

Comment: also see https://audiodiff.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: bascially you cannot do it just with PHP/ Laravel you need to use another utlity to do that